# MySql query - To validate zipcode in two columns in a table against master table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, say master table for ZIPCODE, and a transaction table which contains current address & Permanent address.  Both address columns will have ZIPCODE.  I need to validate these 2 zip codes against the master ZIP table.

```
Master Table:
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A02| TERR NAME 02| NY| 
| 81A04| TERR NAME 04| FL| 
| 81A05| TERR NAME 05| NJ| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA| 
| 81A07| TERR NAME 06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+

Transaction table:
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|Address1_zc|Address2_zc|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A02| 81A05| NY| 
| 81A04| 81A06| FL| 
| 81A05| 90005| NJ| 
| 81A06| 90006| CA| 
| 41A06| 81A06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

The result set should contain only the valid zip codes in both ADDRESS1_ZC & ADDRESS2_ZC.

```
 +-----------+-----------+-----+ 
 |Address1_zc|Address2_zc|state| 
 +-----------+-----------+-----+ 
 | 81A02     | 81A05     | NY  | 
 | 81A04     | 81A06     | FL  | 
 +-----------+-----------+-----+
```

I tried the following SQLs but am unable to get the desired result.

```
select a.Address1_zc, a.Address2_zc from tran_table a 
join master_table b
on a.Address1_zc = b.zipcode
or a.Address2_zc = b.zipcode

select a.Address1_zc, a.Address2_zc from tran_table a 
where a.Address1_zc in (select zipcode from master_table b)
union
select a.Address1_zc, a.Address2_zc from tran_table a 
where a.Address2_zc in (select zipcode from master_table b)
```

The above queries fetches both valid/invalid zip codes.  Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `INNER JOIN`. The following will return rows where both zip codes exist in master table. It assumes that master table does not contain duplicate zip codes.

```
SELECT tran_table.*
FROM tran_table
INNER JOIN master_table AS m1 ON tran_table.address1_zc = m1.zip_code
INNER JOIN master_table AS m2 ON tran_table.address2_zc = m2.zip_code
```

Comment: *"It assumes that master table does not contain duplicate zip codes."*  At first thoughts using `SELECT DISTINCT  tran_table.*` would/should be possible well atleast if the topicstarter does not care which duplication is keept and which ones are filterd out.. But his current dataset does not have a column where we can identify a fixed order from or can use it with `ORDER BY` well maybe the `zip_code` column..

Answer (score 1):

I would want to check the `state` as well as the zip code.  Also, because you need no information from the master table, you can use `exists` in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from tran_table t
where exists (select 1
              from master_table m
              where t.address1_zc = m.zip_code and
                    t.state = m.state
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from master_table m
              where t.address2_zc = m.zip_code and
                    t.state = m.state
             );
```

I prefer `exists` because it generalizes more simply.  If you wanted transactions where the first zip was valid but the second was invalid, then you can just change one to `not exists`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one for small table

```
 select * from transaction_table where Address1_zc in(select Zip_code from master_table) 
    and Address2_zc in (select Zip_code from master_table)
```